# SQL query where a column name contains &

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I have a SQL Server 2008 database, with a column named `ES&D`. I want to query based on that column like this:

```
SELECT ES&D FROM myDB
```

Or this:

```
SELECT * FROM myDB WHERE ES&D=1
```

But I get the following error (I'm using SQL Server Management Studio to write queries):

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'ES'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'D'.

Is there any way to escape the `&` in the column name, such that SQL treats it literally?

Comment: A pox upon whoever created that column name in the first place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes - enclose your column name in square brackets:

```
SELECT [ES&D] FROM myDB
```

That should work - I hope! Same goes for e.g. table or column names with spaces in them (`[Order Details]`), or object names that are SQL keywords, like an `[Order]` table

Comment: Thanks!  It worked perfectly.  That explains why Management Studio inserts brackets for you when creating queries.